# Git issue: Failed to connect (Timed Out)

Tags: git, github, runtime-error, request-timed-out

I'm having the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398764/failed-to-connect-to-github-port-443-maybe-a-firewall-issue#_=_), but unfortunately that did not receive an answer...

Essentially, whenever I try to push/clone to a git repository (whether its from Github or another site), I am unable to do so. I am getting the following error every time:

> fatal: unable to access '(repo url)': Failed to connect to (domain) port 443: Timed Out

Most solutions I found involved setting a proxy, but I am currently not running a proxy. Another idea was that my Firewall may be blocking it.

I was able to push/clone git repositories in the past (about 3 months ago), but since trying again a few days ago it has not worked. My colleagues are able to push/clone from the same repo's I'm trying to access. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Facing same issue. Unable to access any of my repository on bit bucket from ec2 instance. Did you figure out any solution then?

Answer (score 6):

1. Try removing the origin and setting the origin again.

Check the remote

```
$ git remote -v
```

Remove the remote

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

Set the remote again

```
$ git remote set-url origin <url>
```

2. Try to change the url of the remote origin in the .git/config file in your working directory.

   [remote "origin"]

   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

   url = ssh://oldhost.com/usr/local/gitroot/myproject.git

I hope this should help you sort the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. When I changed the config file from "fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/new_repo/*" to "fetch = +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/" and tried pushing, it gave me a fatal: Invalid refspec error.

Comment: @user3342582 Don't change/update the fetch value. Just update the url.

Answer (score 3):

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mdsowmya/Test.git/':
>   Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

**Solutions**:

1. Please check if you are behind any network proxy configured(Internet Options)
   Unset the proxy configuration through git:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

2. If connected to company/office laptop, check your VPN connection/firewall settings.
   Disabling VPN will help you connect to github. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

A minor change to @Vamsi Ravi answer was a change to third step to: `git remote add origin <url>`. After adding the remote once removed I was then able to push as expected.